# JAVA : JDBC template queryForObject: include notnull/empty fields

Tags: java, spring, jdbctemplate

Below query works fine without any issues since it has only one column and I can easily check if its not null and proceed.

```
String query = "SELECT * FROM test WHERE ID=?";
Test test = template.queryForObject(query,new Object[]{id},
                                          new BeanPropertyRowMapper<>(Test.class));
```

I am building a webpage and I have a requirement where I need to generate dynamic queryForObject with only not null column as per user input, how can I do that?

For example in my webpage if I have input fields as id, name and salary and if user inputs just name and ID and doesn't input data for salary, it should dynamically generate below execution statement

```
String query = "SELECT * FROM test WHERE ID=? and name=?" ;
Test test = template.queryForObject(query,new Object[]{id, name},
                                          new BeanPropertyRowMapper<>(Test.class));
```

Comment: I don't think there is anything specific that JDBCTemplate offers you in this scenario. You probably just have to dynamically concatenate the query literal based on the input fields that have data.

Comment: I tried it, but I am not getting expected error, its failing.

Comment: Please share what you've tried.

Comment: new Object[]{id, name} --> This value I am not able to dynamically feed it, its throwing error "SQL state [99999]; error code [17041]; Missing IN or OUT parameter at index:: 2; nested exception is java.sql.SQLException: Missing IN or OUT parameter at index:: 2"

Answer (score 0):

Is this something you are looking for? Quick and dirty way.

```
import org.apache.commons.lang.StringUtils;
import org.springframework.dao.EmptyResultDataAccessException;
import org.springframework.jdbc.core.namedparam.MapSqlParameterSource;
import org.springframework.jdbc.core.namedparam.NamedParameterJdbcTemplate;
import org.springframework.util.CollectionUtils;

import javax.sql.DataSource;
import java.math.BigDecimal;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class TestMe {
    private static DataSource dataSource = null;//@TODO please create datasource
    private static NamedParameterJdbcTemplate jdbcTemplate = new NamedParameterJdbcTemplate(dataSource);

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String criterias = "id=123";
        //criterias = "id=123,name=test;
        //criterias = "id=123,name=test, salary=100.00";
        final List<String> criteriaList = createQueryCriteriaList(criterias);
        Test test = getTest(criteriaList);
        System.out.println(test);
    }


    public static List<String> createQueryCriteriaList(final String criterias) {
        final List<String> queryCriteriaList = new ArrayList<>();
        if (StringUtils.isNotEmpty(criterias)) {
            final String qryCriterias = criterias.replaceAll("[{}]", "");
            for (String criteria : qryCriterias.split(",")) {
                queryCriteriaList.add(criteria);
            }
        }
        return queryCriteriaList;
    }

    public static Test getTest(final List<String> criteriaList) {
        try {
            final MapSqlParameterSource namedParameters = new MapSqlParameterSource();
            final String qry = addCriteriasToQuery("SELECT * FROM test WHERE 1=1 ", criteriaList, namedParameters);
            return jdbcTemplate.queryForObject(qry, namedParameters, (resultSet, i) ->
                    new Test(resultSet.getLong("id"), resultSet.getString("name"),
                            resultSet.getBigDecimal("salary"))
            );
        } catch (EmptyResultDataAccessException emptyExp) {
            return null;
        }
    }

    private static String addCriteriasToQuery(final String query, final List<String> criteriaList,
                                              final MapSqlParameterSource namedParameters) {
        if (CollectionUtils.isEmpty(criteriaList)) {
            return query;
        }
        StringBuilder qryCriteria = new StringBuilder(query);
        for (String criteria : criteriaList) {
            final String[] keyValue = criteria.split("=");
            if (keyValue.length < 2) {
                continue;
            }
            final String key = keyValue[0].trim();
            final String value = keyValue[1];
            switch (key) {
                case "id":
                    qryCriteria.append(" AND id=:id");
                    namedParameters.addValue("id", value);
                    break;
                case "name":
                    qryCriteria.append(" AND name=:name");
                    namedParameters.addValue("name", value);
                    break;
                case "salary":
                    qryCriteria.append(" AND salary=:salary");
                    namedParameters.addValue("salary", value);
                    break;
                default:
                    System.out.println(String.format("Unknown criteria, Key:%s, Value:%s", key, value));
            }
        }
        return qryCriteria.toString();
    }

    static class Test {
        Long id;
        String name;
        BigDecimal salary;

        public Test(Long id, String name, BigDecimal salary) {
            this.id = id;
            this.name = name;
            this.salary = salary;
        }

        public Long getId() {
            return id;
        }

        public void setId(Long id) {
            this.id = id;
        }

        public String getName() {
            return name;
        }

        public void setName(String name) {
            this.name = name;
        }

        public BigDecimal getSalary() {
            return salary;
        }

        public void setSalary(BigDecimal salary) {
            this.salary = salary;
        }
    }
}
```

Note: This is just a sample code and it may have compile or other issues.

Comment: "This is my code with String Builder." what does it mean?